I can't unzip .tar file in the terminal
In downloads there is a file named AmneziaVPN_Linux_Installer.tar, how can I unzip it in terminal?
Linux ubuntu 24.10
I tryed unzip it, but i have error. terminal isn't see my file.
Also i tryed move it to /opt and has this error too
Help me please!

Error is not recoveravle: exiting now

This does not look like a question about programming.

unzip is for zip-files. You have a tar-file. I also don't see, how /opt is related to this.

It's actually quite simple. If I understand your question right, all you should have to do is execute this command:
tar -xopf AmneziaVPN_Linux_Installer.tar

In fact, you can also do this:
tar -x -o -p -f AmneziaVPN_Linux_Installer.tar

Actually, you can also do this:
tar --extract --no-same-owner --preserve-permissions --file AmneziaVPN_Linux_Installer.tar

These commands are all the same because the tar command just has a handy way of compressing multiple arguments into one, like -x -f to -xf. And of course -x is simply a shorter way of saying --extract.
-x means extract, -o means don't preserve file owners after extraction, -p means preserve file permissions after extraction, and -f is just the way of telling tar that the next argument will be the filepath.
Ensure sure you are inside the correct directory before executing this command. If you are not, navigate like:
cd

to go to the home directory (looks something like /home/tango).
cd ..

to go back a directory (/home/tango to /home).
cd directory

to enter a directory (home/tango to /home/tango/directory, replace directory with the desired directory to enter).
cd /home/tango/directory

to go to an absolute path on the filesystem (/home/tango to /home/tango/directory).
